# Possibility to change where Image Transform folders are stored?

Tags: assets, image

When using Inline Transforms in a template and also when the image transform is set in the Image Transforms section of the control panel then say my images folder is located at :

**/images**

And say I create an Image Transform called Square 100 [square100] *(in either way mentioned above)*, the folder with the transformed images get saved to :

**/images/_square100**

Is there any way to prevent this because I'd like to be able to upload images to a certain folder but then have the URL not shown in any way so people can't find the original files. At the moment you can tell that they are in a folder called images and all you'd need to do to access them is to delete the **/_square100** part from the URL.

I tried taking a look at the config variables but couldn't see anything pertaining to this sort of thing or perhaps I'm missing it somewhere?

Many thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 2):

Currently the answer is no.  Those paths are hard set in the code.

Sounds like something for the [feedback site](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/), though.  Be sure and share your use case.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I've gone and added a post to the feedback site.

Comment: I was just about to post this question myself as I assumed it would already be a configuration option. Just added a vote to the feedback page: http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7947945-possibility-to-change-where-image-transform-folder